# Trying to get property of non-object in laravel using haversine formula

Tags: laravel, haversine

i want to get distance to all vehicles from login user but when i apply my queries it returns distance of one vehicle and then show " Trying to get property of non-object" in that line " $latFrom = deg2rad($lat->lat); "

get login user and vehicle latitude and longitude

```
  $users_id = Auth::id();
        // return $users_id;
$lon = DB::table('users')
        ->SELECT('lon')
        ->where("id", $users_id)
        ->first();
$lat = DB::table('users')
        ->SELECT('lat')
        ->where("id", $users_id)
        ->first();

$vehicles=DB::table('vehicle')
            ->get();
```

my haversine formula

```
   function haversineGreatCircleDistance(
  $lat, $lon, $vehicle_lat, $vehicle_lon, $earthRadius = 6371000)
{      

    // return $lon;
  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($lat->lat);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($lon->lon);
  $latTo   = deg2rad($vehicle_lat);
  $lonTo   = deg2rad($vehicle_lon);

  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

  $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
  return $angle * $earthRadius;
}
```

after applying haversine i print the distance

```
foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
                $center_lat = $lat;
                $center_lng = $lon;
                $lat=$vehicle->lat;
                $lng=$vehicle->lon;

                $distance = haversineGreatCircleDistance($center_lat, $center_lng, $lat, $lng, 6371);
print($distance);
}
```

Comment: Why are you fetching the same user 3 times from the database? `Auth::id()`, `$lat` and `$lon` all get the same user.. just use `Auth::user()->lat` / `Auth::user()->lon`

Comment: sorry i am new in laravel , thanks it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have a few weird things going on in your code. It's hard to know exactly what is going wrong with the $latFrom line as it's looks like $lat should be an object just glancing at your code. My guess is it's returning null or being set to null before it gets to the distance function.

You can check this by doing a `dd($lat)` and seeing what is actually being returned from within the controller. It'll dumb out the value right on the screen. You can dump out the query log to see what query is actually be executed as well to further trouble shoot.

[Example option for dumping query in Laravel 7](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#debugging)

But in this case I would just refactor a bit, since you really don't need to do a database call for $lon and $lat at all. It's all the same user, and laravel already fills in the auth user for you anyway which can be retrieved using the Auth::user() command.
`$user = Auth::user();`

Then $user->lat, and $user->lon will have the lat and lon from the database.

Alternately you can do `Auth::user()->lat`, and `Auth::user()->lon` without saving it to a separate user variable first as well.

In your vehicle loop:

```
foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
    $distance = havesineGreatCircleDistance($user->lat, $user->lon, $vehicle->lat, $vehicle->lon);
}
```

Note I didn't bother setting the variable before putting it in the function since that isn't anything to gain by that unless you want to reference them with those names after that point for some reason.

Then in the function

```
$latFrom = deg2rad($lat);
$lonFrom = deg2rad($lon);
```

Notice the difference here with just doing $lat instead of $lat->lat. Using this method they won't be objects just values so you won't want to reference them as objects.